# Wrist pain when bearing weight and bending both sides

Tags: pain, orthopedics, wrist

Let me explain it from when it started. 2018 begining I started feeling very light pain in the middle of my right wrist joint when ever I use it to stand up pushing my self using my right hand agents the ground when Im sitting or standing. It gradually started to increase until it became sharp and painful. When it first started I said to my self it will heal its normal. Now its bin more than two years and its very painful to use it when bearing weight on it. I went to 5 Doc so far but no one told me exactly whats the issue.the first doctor suggested me a flexible splint that will prevent me from bending my wrist and after few days the pain was go. He told me to wear it for 6 months and thats what I did but after 6 months I was still feeling the pain when bearing weight in an open position of the wrist. Then we did X ray and it was normal. then the Dr suggested an arthrogram mri where the MRI report said I have a TFCC tear. Went back to the doctor and examine my wrist but the pain location was not similar to the TFCC tear thats what he said. I lost hope with this doctor and went to 4 more doctors but same results. One doctor gave me a steroid Injection in my wrist and inflammation medication as he was suspected wrist synovitis. Waited for 4 weeks wearing my splint but after it was still painful. What I observed that there is a small pump in the middle or my wrist. It is only visible when I bend my hand forward. One doctor said it might be a ganglion but I dont think ganglion should be doing these symptoms. I can lift Items with no pain as long as my wrist is not bend. if there is any suggestion to what might be the issue it will really help. Any other tests i can perform to confirm its a TFCC as no pain from my right side only the middle.[image: Wrist Pain Location]
[image: Small Pump appears when bending]